# How do I publish a Gradle project to maven repository with 'optional' and 'provided' scope?

Tags: maven-2, gradle, maven-3

I see how gradle can deploy to a maven repository automatically generating the POM required to do it.  How can this be so for dependencies that I would set to true and/or provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GRADLE-784](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRADLE-784) has a provided scope workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle plugin "[propdeps-plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin)" solves this.

Answer (score 0):

The WAR-Plugin (see http://gradle.org/war_plugin) now offers 
providedRuntime and providedComplile.
But the provided scope does not exist in general.